# Ubuntu Studio 20.04 not rebooting after update

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, updates, reboot, ubuntu-studio

My Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS corrupted so I proceeded with a clean install as I have done many times before. I am installing on a 500 GB EXT4 freshly formatted partition (I have a second 500GB partition formatted in EXT4 for data)

After the clean install from CD, Ubuntu Studio reboots the first time just fine. Shortly after, as usual, it requests updating and a reboot. But now, it no longer reboots at all. The WiFi network light stays on, the HDD light flashes briefly once a minute or so, and the screen remain black. *I have repeated the process and Einstein must be laughing at me ;-)*

Has anyone experienced this? Is it a recent 20.04 patch that may have a bug?
I do not think that it is a hardware issue, it reboots fine after the clean install.

What should I do?

- Wait a long long time for it to finish (I somewhat doubt that, it has been hours now)
- Diagnostics (boot from CD in safe mode and do what?)
- Not update 20.04 LTS at all. Avoid certain updates?
- Migrate to 22.04 LTS?

I have a LENOVO W520:

- Intel Core i7-2760QM processor (quad-core, 2.4GHz) 2GB
- NVIDIA Quadro® 2000M graphics
- 24 GB PC3-10600 1333MHz DDR3 Memory
- 4-in-1 media reader (MMC, SD, SDHC, SDXC)
- 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Bluetooth 3.0
- 1 GB SSD HDD

Many thanks in advance,

Paul.

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER:** WAIT 2 HOURS FOR THE SOFTWARE TO UPDATE.
PATIENCE FOLKS !!!

I guess there are a lot more patches since 1st release.
*Note: Installing from the DVD takes only about 15 minutes.*